# Why does Perl this program fail to print "Success" when the regex match succeeds?

Tags: regex, perl

I am still a beginner with Perl, so please bear with me. This is the situation I'm experiencing:

```
$var = "AB1234567";
$num = "1234567";
next if $var =~ /$num/;
print "Success!\n";
```

Now, my understanding is that it should print "Success!\n", but in reality it doesn't.  However, if I change the regex to `next if $var =~ /"$num"/;`, this will actually print "Success!\n".

However, if I change it to `$var = "AB123456";`, the original regex will work fine.

I understand that when enclosing strings using double quotations, it will <s>dereference</s> interpolate the variable. However, should it not be true in the case of regex? I've done regex using variables without quotations and it worked fine.

Thanks for your help!

#### EDIT:

I left out semi-colons in my example, but my original problem still stands.

#### EDIT:

I really should've just copied/pasted. I made a typo and used `continue if` instead of `next if`. Again, my problem still exists.

Comment: "dereference" is the wrong word. It will *interpolate* the value. Of course "string" or "stringify" the value would work there too.

Comment: Oh, I see, I see. Thanks. Now I learned a new word =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused on what `continue` does. I'm not really sure of what you are trying to do here, but generally `continue` will break out of an if-block or go to the next iteration of a for-loop, while-loop, etc. When the pattern does match, `continue` is actually skipping over the print statement. When you change the value of `$var`, it no longer matches and the print statement is reached.

Try this:

```
$var = "AB1234567"
$num = "1234567"
print "Success!\n" if $var =~ /$num/;
```

Randy

Comment: Good catch. I think I meant to use "next if" instead. I'll try your example right now.

Comment: Hmm...no, your example still didnt work for me. Thanks though.

Comment: Actually, your example did work for me. It didn't work at first because I left the "next if" statement before it. Thanks, although I'm still curious why my original code doesn't work.

Comment: @Evan See my answer to understand why your original code does not work. Then, read `perldoc perlsyn` also available at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. This works for me:

```
$var = "AB1234567";
$num = "1234567";
print "Success!\n" if $var =~ /$num/;
```

It is either something with your continue statement or the fact that you are missing semicolons in the variable assignments (your example doesn't even run for me....).

Comment: Oops, I forgot about those semi-colons. I have edited my original post to include them now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at your code:

```
$var = "AB1234567";
$num = "1234567";
next if $var =~ /$num/;
print "Success!\n";
```

I am assuming this is in the body of some loop. When you say

```
next if $var =~ /$num/;
```

You are saying "go back and execute the loop body for the next iteration, skipping any following statements in the look body **if** `$var` matches `/$num/`". When `$var` does indeed match `/$num/`, the program does exactly what you asked for and skips the `print` statement.

On the other hand, when you use `$var =~ /"$num"/`, the pattern on the right hand side becomes `/"1234567"/`. Now, the conditional in `next if $var =~ /"$num"/` cannot succeed. And, your program prints `"Success"` because the match failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use re 'debug';

my $num = "1234567";

for my $var ( qw( AB1234567 ) ) {
    next if $var =~ /$num/;
    print "Success!\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Compiling REx "1234567"
Final program:
   1: EXACT  (4)
   4: END (0)
anchored "1234567" at 0 (checking anchored isall) minlen 7
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "1234567" against "AB1234567"
Found anchored substr "1234567" at offset 2...
Starting position does not contradict /^/m...
Guessed: match at offset 2
Freeing REx: "1234567"
```

Now, let's use **`/"$num"/`** as the pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use re 'debug';

my $num = "1234567";

for my $var ( qw( AB1234567 ) ) {
    next if $var =~ /"$num"/;
    print "Success!\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Compiling REx "%"1234567%""
Final program:
   1: EXACT  (5)
   5: END (0)
anchored "%"1234567%"" at 0 (checking anchored isall) minlen 9
Guessing start of match in sv for REx "%"1234567%"" against "AB1234567"
Did not find anchored substr "%"1234567%""...
Match rejected by optimizer
Success!
Freeing REx: "%"1234567%""
```

Your code prints **Success!** when the match fails.

See also [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control):

> The `next` command starts the next iteration of the loop:

```
    LINE: while (<STDIN>) {
    next LINE if /^#/;  # discard comments
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html

```
C:>perl -e "$x='abc'; $y='bc'; print 'yes' if index($x,$y)>0;"
yes
C:>perl -e "$x='abc'; $y='bc'; print 'yes' if $x =~ /$y/"
yes
```

If (as is implied) the code is in a loop, you might be interested in `qr{}` in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators

Comment: Well, my original example wasn't in a loop, and I'm betting you saw my original code where I used "continue if". I meant to use "next if". Thanks for your reply though =)  The link you provided me gave me a better understanding of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says "If this variable matches this regular expression, do nothing.  Otherwise, print `Success!`.".  I doubt that's what you meant for it to do.

Adding the quotation marks does not affect whether the variable is interpolated at all.  What it *does* do is cause the regular expression match to fail.  Since the match fails, the `next`[1] is not executing and execution reaches the print statement and `Success!` is printed.

The problem with your code is not at all related to regular expressions or to variable interpolation into regular expressions or to quotation marks appearing inside regular expressions.  It is a simple logic error of an inverted conditional.

Try replacing the third line with

```
next unless $var =~ /$num/;
```

to see what happens when you simply invert the logic of your code to what you probably intended.

[1]: or `continue`, depending on which version of your code one is looking at